# Conocer origen tras un load

Tags: javascript, div

Muy buenas, estoy atascado en algo, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

tengo el siguiente código:

```
$('#IdCre').load('crea.php');
```

Esto carga una web "Crea.php" en un div, el problema está en que en crea.php tengo un boton de atras, y dependiendo desde donde hago el load, se tiene que ir a un lado o a otro.

Me explico de otra forma. Cuando estoy en la web crea.php, al darle al boton de anterior, oculto el div actual y muestro otro. El problema es que el div que tengo que mostar dependera de desde donde cargo el load.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la manera mas rapida para esto es usar get si no te preocupan las acciones "indevidas".

Primero en el load cargas los datos que quieres:

```
$('#IdCre').load('crea.php?url=orgien');
```

Donde origen sera la pagina actual. No es necesario que pongas toda la url, basta con saber el nombre. Ya le añadiras extension etc cuando la trates.

Finalmente la recoges en la pagina crea.php con un get.

```
var url = new URL(urlactual);
var c = url.searchParams.get("url");
```

Cargas la url actual. Una vez guardada la pasamos por `.searchParams.get("url")` donde url sera el nombre del parametro y la variable `c` sera finalmente el origen deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, es lo primero que pense, pero por alguna razón no aparece la url, debe ser por que es una pagina cargada en un div.  La web la carga bien y la muestra pero en la barra de direcciones no aparece nada. Un saludo.

Comment: Mis disculpas, tienes razón, se puede hacer perfectamente por ese metodo. Un saludo